# feedpp and session ID

Tags: perl, rss, feed, sessionid

we are using Perl and cpan Modul FeedPP to parse RSS Feeds.
The Perl script runs trough the different items of the RSS Feeds and save the link to the database, liket his:

```
my $response = $ua->get($url);

if ($response->is_success) {
        my $feed = XML::FeedPP->new( $response->content, -type => 'string' );
                foreach my $item ( $feed->get_item() ) {
                        my $link = $item->link();
                        [...]
```

`$url` contains the URL to an RSS Feed, like `http://my.domain/RSS/feeds.xml`

in this case,  `$item->link()` will contain links to the RSS article, like `http://my.domain/topic/myarticle.html`

The Problem is, some webservers (which provides the RSS feeds) does an HTTP refer in order to add an session ID to the URL, like this: `http://my.domain/RSS/feeds.xml;jsessionid=4C989B1DB91D706C3E46B6E30427D5CD`.

The strange think is, that feedPP seams to add this session-ID to the link of every item. So `$item->link()` contain links to the RSS article, like `http://my.domain/topic/myarticle.html;jsessionid=4C989B1DB91D706C3E46B6E30427D5CD`

Even if the original link does not contain an session ID.

Is there a way to turn of that behavior of feedPP??

Thank you for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look through [http://metacpan.org/pod/XML::FeedPP](http://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aFeedPP) but didn't see any way to turn have the link() method trim those session IDs for you.  (I'm using XML::FeedPP in one of my scripts and the site I happen to be parsing doesn't use session IDs.)

So I think the answer is no, not currently.  You could try contacting the author or filing a bug.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the behavior is correct: uri components which follow a semi-colon are defined part of the path (configuration parameter for interpretation), so when the uri is used to make a relative url into an absolute uri it needs to be copied as well.

You expect compatible behavior with '&' parameters, but they are not equal.
https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=73895